# Calling the base class directly in the derived class constructor argument

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 2 classes:

```
public class LineGeometry
{
    public LineGeometry(Point startPoint, Vector direction) 
    {
        this.startPoint = startPoint; this.direction = direction;        
    }
}

public class LineSegmentGeometry : LineGeometry
{
    Point endPoint;
    public LineSegmentGeometry(Point startPoint, Point endPoint, Vector direction) : base (startPoint, direction)
    {
        this.startPoint = startPoint; this.direction = direction; this.endPoint = endPoint;        
    }
}
```

Essentially, I am hoping to add one more constructor to `LineSegmentGeometry` that goes something like this:

```
LineSegmentGeometry(Point endPoint, LineGeometry l)
{
    this.startPoint = l.startPoint;
    this.direction = l.direction;      
    this.endPoint = endPoint;
}
```

Since essentially `LineSegmentGeometry` is exactly the same as its base class, with the exception of 1 additional variable.

However the compiler throws an error that the base class is inaccessible due to its protection level. Is this way of declaring the constructor a good idea and if it is okay, how do I go about resolving the error?

Comment: As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend sticking to one statement per line. It makes it much easier to read. Also, currently your class declarations are invalid (you don't want those `()`) and your `LineSegmentGeometry` class doesn't derive from `LineGeometry`.

Comment: Thanks edited for the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you should just call up to the base class constructor:

```
LineSegmentGeometry(Point endPoint, LineGeometry l)
    : base(l.StartPoint, l.Direction)
{
    this.endPoint = endPoint;
}
```

Note that I'm referring to `StartPoint` and `Direction` as properties - I'd expect the *fields* to be private, but there to be public or internal *properties* exposing the values. If there aren't, then you could add a `LineGeometry(LineGeometry)` constructor, and use `: base(l)` instead, and let *that* copy the fields.